# How to set document_id in elastic using logstash config file

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash-configuration

I want to pass dynamic value to document_id in elastic using my log file.
Example -(xx.log file)

```
{"level":"info","item_id":"123","message":"Hii","timestamp":"2017-02-02T08:32:09.535Z"}
```

I want to pass my log file field value "item_id" in my elastic "document_id" value, and my logstash.conf output section file -

```
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
      elasticsearch {
           host => "localhost" 
           document_id => "%{item_id}"
      }
 }
```

Comment: In your `elasticsearch` output, `host` should be `hosts`. Aside from that it should work. What error or result do you get?

Comment: in elasticsearch its show like ```{ _index: '',_id:'{item_id}' ....}```

Comment: Ok in that document it looks like you missed the `%` sign. Works now?

Comment: yes. as it's. like-  { _index: '',_id:'%{item_id}' ....}

Comment: Can you verify that in that document you have a field called `item_id` ??

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which should work fine :-

```
input {

}  

filter {

} 

output {  
    stdout {  
        codec => rubydebug   
    }
    elasticsearch {  
        hosts       => "http://localhost:9200"  
        index       => "name_of_index"  
        document_id => "%{item_id}"
        action      => index
    }  
}
```